# how to select a weeks amount of dates from a database?

Tags: c#, database, datetime, linq-to-sql

What I am trying to do is search my database (ado.net with linq to sql) for all entrys within the last week.

The database has a field called date and I need the entries that are 7 days previous to the current date.

```
var records = (from r in context.PumpInfoTables
               where r.Date.Equals(DateTime.Now)
               //&& where r.date <= 7 days <--help
               select r);
```

so I am looking for some help with this query, is there a between function that can be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DateTime weekFromNow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
var records = (from r in context.PumpInfoTables
                           where r.Date < DateTime.Now
                           && r.Date >= weekFromNow
                           select r);
```

Comment: Be aware of the following: If this query is executed at 10 am on Monday, it wouldn't return the rows from last Monday at 9 am. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: True. Look at @DanielHilgarth answer in that case. (I'll leave this code as is)

Answer (score 3):

This is really simple:

```
var oneWeekAgo = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
var records = (from r in context.PumpInfoTables
               where r.Date >= oneWeekAgo
               select r);
```

This assumes that you don't have entries from the future. If you do have, use this instead:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var oneWeekAgo = today.AddDays(-7);
var records = (from r in context.PumpInfoTables
               where r.Date >= oneWeekAgo && r.Date <= today + 1
               select r);
```

Please note:
My code uses `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now`, assuming you are only interested in the date part, not the time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
var records = (from r in context.PumpInfoTables
                           where r.Date > DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7)
                           select r);
```

Comment: If `r.Date equals DateTime.Now` it is always greater than the date 7 days ago, making the second condition redundant. And it would only return those rows with a date of *right now*. Most likely, this will never return anything. It surely won't return the rows of the past week.